# python - add inputted message to .txt file

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is create a function that saves the user's answer to a prompt and puts it into a .txt file.

I use sys to do this, but it failed to properly put the user's answer into the file.
it deleted the user's answer from the .txt file to make a new space for the newest one.

are there any other modules that could help with my request?

Comment: Sounds like you want to open the file [in append mode instead of write mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file)

Comment: Please show your current code and state what doesnt work about it or what your trying to fix

Comment: im not trying to fix my code. I just needed modules so I can code with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you need something like this

```py
question = input("Your question: ")


def write_ans_to_file(answer, filename="answers.txt"):
    with open(filename, "a") as e:
        e.write(answer)
        e.write("\n")

write_ans_to_file(question)
```